# Editorfor Html.LabelFor is blank when Value is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating some EditorTemplates to bundle labels, controls, and validation together (along with other stuff I've removed to simplify the example). This one is for a nullable decimal, and I've found it to work fine unless the decimal is null in which case the Label is not displayed (the html label markup and the desired label text goes missing).

```
@model decimal?

@{
    @Html.LabelFor(v => v)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(v => v)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(v => v)
}
```

Here's the property in the model:

```
[Display(Name = "Label Me This")]
public Nullable<decimal> MyDecimal { get; set; }
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm. It works fine for me using your template. How are you calling the editor? What version of MVC?

Comment: @SimonC I'm just calling `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDecimal)`. It's MVC 6.0.0-rc1-final. Hopefully this isn't a core bug.

Comment: Ah, right. Works fine in MVC5.

Comment: Also fine in AspnetCore.Mvc 1.01. Maybe a bug in that package.

Comment: @SimonC thanks for trying it in those enviros.